# Is Geoserver's "styler" plugin dead?

Tags: geoserver, style, coding-style

The "Styler" plugin for Geoserver promised flexible styling of your data, using the GeoExt library:

[image: GeoExt Styler]

The [user guide](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/styler.html) tells you to first install the REST plugin, and then extract the styler zip file into the /data/www Geoserver directory. However, the download page for [Geoserver 2.2](http://geoserver.org/display/GEOS/All+Releases) does not include the REST plugin. Installing older versions (I'm using Geoserver 2.2) failed for me, with one error saying "This web site needs a different Google Maps API key" (from /geoserver/www/styler/ - I have a Google Maps API).

REST seems to have disappeared recently: versions [up to 2.0.3](http://geoserver.org/display/GEOS/GeoServer+2.0.1) contained the option to download the REST zip package, whereas after that there is no mention of REST, and the installation guide remains.

I did find some evidence that REST may have died, [however](http://geoserver.org/display/GEOS/GeoExt+Styler):

> This feature is no longer updated as an independent GeoServer download, but is available as part of the OpenGeo Suite. For more information on its development see OpenGeo project page

If Geoserver's "styler" plugin really is dead, then I should probably change the question to something more general like "how do I make [OpenGeo's Styler](http://projects.opengeo.org/styler/) work on Geoserver?" Just wanted to check with others who've had similar experience.

**Context**
I've set-up Geoserver on an AWS EC2 instance (testing map can be seen [here](http://robinlovelace.vacau.com/awn.html)).
What I'm trying to do is to make those boring grey polygons colourful and interesting, based on their attributes. I've tried exporting the sld that discribes the style below into Geoserver, but, at present, this does not work.

[image: styled-polys]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OpenGeo Suite's [GeoExplorer](http://blog.opengeo.org/tag/geoexplorer/) now has the styling capability that Styler used to have. That must be why they shelved it.

[image]

You can get the code and installation instructions at [Github](https://github.com/opengeo/GeoExplorer).

Comment: That looks great - installed GeoExplorer and I now get something similar to your screenshot at 8080/geoexplorer/composer/ . The original install (in tomcat/webapps) could load data from my geoserver but could not save new styles etc. The second install (in geoserver/data/www) could do neither. Should I install opengeo from scratch from here https://github.com/opengeo/suite?

Comment: Did you log in? You can only save if you've logged in. It would be much easier to just use the OpenGeo Suite though.

Answer (score 3):

The REST plugin no longer exists for GeoServer as it has been incorporated into the core. You should not have to install anything, the REST API should work out of the box. You can test by using the URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest
```

The [GeoServer documentation](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/restconfig/index.html) provides some good information about the REST API.

Comment: Sounds good but does not work in my case: I get the following text from 8080/geoserver/rest: Geoserver Configuration API    workspaces,
    namespaces,
    styles,
    layers,
    layergroups,
    reload,
    reset. Clicking on these results in a page of garbled text such as "HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang...." for the "workspaces" link.
.

Comment: That means the REST is present but you GeoServer is suffering from some form of failure. I suggest you raise a question on the Geoserver-Devel email list to see if this is a known issue. I am running GeoServer 2.2.1 and my REST API is working correctly. Clicking on one of those items should give you another page of details, not 500 error!

Comment: Thanks for the information. REST may have been damaged on my GeoServer when it was manually installed. Because of this, and the advantages of GeoExplorer and other goodies, thinking of starting from scratch and installing OpenGeo stack instead. Let me know if you've any further advice: greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The rest plugin is already built-in in the latest version of GeoServer. Only the styler's file that is needed to extract in the GeoServer directory and it is ready to use.