# No Layers available in GeoExt Styler for GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, style, geoext, extensions

I´m searching for a styler to create styles for my data and I stumbled over the *styler extension* for GeoServer 2.6.1.

I that the REST-Plugin is now is integrated in GeoServer and i only had to "install" the styler-plugin (extract the zip-file to the www-directory).
If I open the styler-page (`localhost:8080/geoserver/www/styler/index.html`) in the browser I get the styler-page but the layer-panel is blank. There are no layers shown.
It seems that there is no connection between the styler and the geoserver.

Is there anything i have to configure somewhere?

Comment: http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/GeoEXT-Styler-td3795928.html - indicates others have the same problem, plus a few possible solutions.

Comment: yeah, i found that one, too. and that one [link](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/40823/is-geoservers-styler-plugin-dead)

Comment: But they refer to older versions of GeoServer where the REST-Plugin had to be installed manually. I tried (localhost:8080/geoserver/rest) and get to the GeoServer Configuration API, so REST seems to work fine. In your link, one user mentioned to check if the wms capabilities doc is corrupted, but i don´t have an idea, where i can found this doc.

Comment: Some of those seem to be more recent; it'd be nice if there was a date. As to the WMS GetCapabilites, these can be had by using the link on the right side of the main GeoServer Admin page. It may be worth asking this on the GeoServer user mailing list.